# What do you suggest I use for statically creating a collection of string values?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-4.0

Here is how I'm doing things now, declaring the string of `Roles` allowed to access my controller action method:

```
[Role(Roles="Regular User, Accounting, Administrator")]
public ActionResult ChangeAvatar()
{
    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        var user = _userRepository.FindUserByEmail(User.Identity.Name);
        var model = new ChangeAvatarModel();
        model.CurrentAvatarUrl = user.AvatarUrl;

        return View(model);
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
}
```

I don't want to write up the `Roles` as a string because I may mistype and cause an unexpected bug. I'd rather write them once and be done with it.

What do you suggestion I use for this use case? A `dictionary<enum, string>`?

```
[Role(Roles=DefinedRoles.Accounting)] // Would return string: "Regular User, Account"
public ActionResult ChangeAvatar()
{
    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        var user = _userRepository.FindUserByEmail(User.Identity.Name);
        var model = new ChangeAvatarModel();
        model.CurrentAvatarUrl = user.AvatarUrl;

        return View(model);
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a static constants class:

```
public static class DefinedRoles
{
    public const string Accounting = "Regular User, Accounting, Administrator";
}
```

Comment: Definitely the simplest approach.

Comment: Well - now I feel silly. Time to get up and go for a walk. Thanks!

Comment: This is not type safe though, you will still require the string datatype which can contain any value. Imagine new developer joining the team not knowing there is a constant defined. He will be passing a string without using the constant. I'd look further for a type safe solution.

Answer (score 0):

Currently experimenting with this approach, so far so good..

```
public class StringEnum
{
    private static IDictionary<string, StringEnum> _items = new Dictionary<string, StringEnum>();

    public static readonly StringEnum Type1 = new StringEnum("TYPE1");
    public static readonly StringEnum Type2 = new StringEnum("TYPE2");

    private string _value;

    private StringEnum(string value)
    {
        _value = value;
        _items.Add(_value, this);
    }

    public static implicit operator StringEnum(string value)
    {
        return _items[value];
    }

    public static implicit operator string(StringEnum typeSafeValue)
    {
        return typeSafeValue._value;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return obj.ToString() == _value;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return base.GetHashCode();
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return _value;
    }
}
```

Can be used like:

```
StringEnum type = StringEnum.Type1
```

Comment: Hi @Shikyo, you may want to take a look at SpecializedEnum on Codeplex if you want to go the enum-style route. http://specializedenum.codeplex.com/